# Custom class in C# combo box, Linq dynamic cast to string crashes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I wrote a generic class that gets stored inside of a combo box item list, using a key/value for a database identifier and it's string label value.  This way selecting an index I get it's DB primary key and a string label for visual purposes.  The issue is, I am overriding the combo box to do an enhanced Suggest/append search using substrings and not just searching "StartsWith" like the default combo box does in C# / .NET.

The issue, is using linq (sub class of ComboBox component):

```
private Expression<Func<ObjectCollection, IEnumerable<string>>> _propertySelector

_suggBindingList.Clear();
_suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
_propertySelectorCompiled(Items) //Items is ObjectCollection <-- crashes
    .Where(_filterRuleCompiled)
    .OrderBy(_suggestListOrderRuleCompiled)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(_suggBindingList.Add);
_suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
_suggBindingList.ResetBindings();
```

The simple solution is to just manually loop through items instead and cast/convert manually, but I was hoping there was a simpler way to allow my combo box DataItem custom class to be casted to a string at runtime...so the code above would work normally on regular combo box data or key/value pair custom class combo box items I have added in.  The ToString() of the class just uses the label to represent itself as a string, which I assumed would cover this but I guess not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, doing an explicit conversion makes sense across classes and objects by adding a static method to the specific class but not sure for primitive types like string..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there wasn't an easy generic way I could find w/ linq, so instead I just wrote code to rely on .ToString() accordingly so objects (even my custom ones) we're represented in string format and operated on accordingly. So I made a generic way, just removed linq because it would crash on my custom classes and doesn't appear to invoke the ToString() override, just run time cast and fails.

Oh well, still a clean generic solution but using linq was nice. Unfortunately linq is now gone in the solution.